# Does all devices support OpenGL?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, version, android-library

I am trying to use the [WaveInApp](https://github.com/Cleveroad/WaveInApp) library in my application.

According to the README file, I have to add the OpenGL ES 2.0 as a feature to my Manifest.

In the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl) the OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported by Android 2.2, but what is exactly the meaning of this?

My project support the minimum API of 17. Does this mean that all devices that has a version greater than Android 2.2 will work with this library? Since I am supporting Android version 4+, will all my users be able to use this library on their devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, it means that every Android version starting with 2.2 is supported and if you take a look at the [Android 8.1 compatibility definition](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.1/android-8.1-cdd) for example, you'll see that OpenGL ES 2.0 is still supported.

So yes, with your minimum API of 17 every user of your Android app should have a smartphone that supports this library.